# Data gets messed up when sent between two devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I built a multiplayer game which works perfectly on my iPhone 5s played against the simulator. But whenever I try to play from my 5s against an iPhone 5, there are some problems.

The game sends two values to the other player: score and level.

In case the iPhone 5s sends the values: iPhone 5 thinks score = 0 and level = the value we sent as the score.

```
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger score;
    NSUInteger level;
} MessageNewScore;

- (void)sendData:(NSData *)data {
    NSError *error;
    GameKitHelper *gameKitHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];

    BOOL success = [gameKitHelper.match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending data:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}

// Run on iPhone 5s
- (void)sendNewScore:(NSUInteger)score level:(NSUInteger)level{
    NSLog(@"score: %lu", (unsigned long)score); // E.g. 1930
    NSLog(@"level: %lu", (unsigned long)level); // E.g. 7

    MessageNewScore messageNewScore;
    messageNewScore.message.messageType = kMessageTypeNewScore;
    messageNewScore.score = score;
    messageNewScore.level = level;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&messageNewScore
                              length:sizeof(MessageNewScore)];

    [self sendData:data];

    NSLog(@"score: %lu", (unsigned long)messageNewScore.score); // 1930
    NSLog(@"level: %lu", (unsigned long)messageNewScore.level); // 7
}

// Run on iPhone 5
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
    MessageNewScore *messageNewScore = (MessageNewScore*)[data bytes];

    NSLog(@"score: %lu", (unsigned long)messageNewScore->score); // According to iPhone 5 this is 0
    NSLog(@"level: %lu", (unsigned long)messageNewScore->level); // According to iPhone 5 this is 1930

    [_delegate enemysScoreReceived:messageNewScore->score level:messageNewScore->level];
}
```

In the last case, the values from logging in `sendNewScore::` are correct and in `didReceiveData::` are wrong.
I figured this could have something to do with the 64-bit processor in the 5s, but not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why not use an `NSDictionary` to send your data as key/value pairs instead of a struct?

Comment: Hmm, never thought about it. It was done this way in the tutorial I used.

Comment: @yoeriboven Tutorial may be older than iPhone 5S (64-bit).

Comment: Yes, it was. Had to find other ways to do something due to deprecated methods a few times.

Comment: why the heck did you get down voted? I have this exact question, thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone 5 uses uses an Apple A6 (32-bit), the iPhone 5S an Apple A7 (64-bit) processor.

You need to encode/decode `NSData` that is sent between players in a portable representation, such as can be obtained with `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` for encoding/decoding `NSInteger`s, etc. You are currently sending `struct`s whose representation is processor-specific.

Comment: Never used `NSKeyedArchiver` before. Could you show some example code?

Comment: @yoeriboven initialize an instance with `initForWritingWithMutableData:`, then call `encodeInt:withKey:`, etc., as needed.

Comment: Or simply change the `struct` types from `NSUInteger` to a fixed size type such as `uint32_t`.

Comment: @rmaddy (... and wait until an architecture with a different byte order may come along)

Comment: @Drux That's easily handled as well using one of the many existing byte-ordering functions.

Comment: @rmaddy (... which `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` uses internally). Actually `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` is not optimal because Apple wants us to use compact representations. So I'm using a custom `CompactingKeyed(Un)Archiver`. But it's good enough to get started.

Comment: @Drux Am curious by your comment about The Compacting(Un)Archiver, could you please share some thoughts or implementation of it? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig It offers the same contract as a `Keyed(Un)Archiver` except that I also `init` it with an `NSDictionary` that tells it how many bits of representation to use for each key. That way e.g. `BOOL`s can be encoded into single bits. It also handles portability as mentioned here.

Comment: @Drux Very interesting. If you could gist that, I would really like to see it. But if it's not OK, no problem, I understand. Just trying to ask. Thanks again for response.

Comment: @Unheilig will consider.